# Is there any way I can enforce a process's base address?

Tags: c, process, mmap

When create a process, how does the system designate its base address? Is there anyway I can enforce it? For example, I have an address `0x55d1008fc000`, and I'd like the process to always start from this address.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: Does this answer your question? [disable the randomness in malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003431/disable-the-randomness-in-malloc)

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This solution completely disable the randomization. But in my case, I would want only deterministicity on a certain process, but not others. So I was hoping to find more information about how the system designate a base address when create a process.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: 64~18.04.1-Ubuntu